# Express difference between two positive numbers as a number between $0$ and $1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, arithmetic

It looks like a relatively simple problem, but I found some difficulties finding a way to express the difference between two numbers as a number in between $0$ and $1$ (you can say as a percentage).

Rules are simple: both numbers are always positive, and regardless of how big each of two numbers is, the difference between them must be expressed as any number between $0$ and $1$.

A usual

> $\frac{x-y}{y}=$ difference

Doesn't work here, since if $X$ is much better than $Y$, their difference will be expressed as a number larger than $1$. Any simple variation of this formula gives the same results.

How would you make sure that difference can be expressed within boundaries of $0$ and $1$, regardless of how big or small either $X$ or $Y$ is?

Comment: You could try $\frac{x-y}{x+y}$. Although, "expressing the difference between two numbers" as $\frac{23}{57}$ no matter what the two numbers are is another possibility—unless we have specific properties that this expressed-difference should have.

Comment: Well, depending on how big the numbers you're working with get, you can always set some really big bound on how far the two numbers are. Say that bound is $10^9$. Then the difference between $350$ and $1547$ would be $0.0001197$, which is the percentage of $10^9$ corresponding to $1547-350$. I don't think there's a good way to generalize this to arbitrarily big numbers though.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade Well, I said big number, not in a way that approaches infinity or anything like that. My main goal is simply to get the difference expressed between 0 and 1.

Comment: @GregMartin If x - y will give us a negative number, the difference will be expressed as a negative number as well. The goal is to keep it in between 0 and 1.

Comment: You could just take the absolute value of Greg's expression; i.e., $\frac{|x-y|}{x+y}$ to remedy this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the two numbers be $a$ and $b$ which are positive integers and let $x=a-b$. You could use the sigmoid function or any variant of it as it is used in neural networks in computer science, only retuning a number of 0 to 1. The function is:

$$f(x)=\frac{e^x}{e^x+1}$$

If you feel this goes from 0 to 1 too quickly and only expresses the difference between two small numbers accurately, you could change the value of $c,n\in\mathbb{R}^+$ in:

$$f(x)=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{n}(x-c)}}{e^{\frac{1}{n}(x-c)}+1}$$

You can use this https://www.desmos.com/calculator/x0budxt4uq as a visualisation, though really large differences (which is denoted by d in the desmos graph), eventually leads to the function equalling $1$ (or so close the computer can't calculate the decimal points). You can also use any of the functions on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function under the examples section, which also all give out a number from  $0$ to $1$ no matter the input. To summarise, it is probably impossible to find a function which expresses the difference between two numbers linearly, as I am pretty certain it has to exceed one at one point. You will probably have to use functions which asymptote at $0$ and $1$ such as the sigmoid function of functions alike. I hope this helps!